# How do I escape parentheses in java 7?

Tags: java

I'm trying to split some input from BufferedReader.readLine()

```
String delimiters = " ,()";
String[] s = in.readLine().split(delimiters);
```

This gives me a runtime error.

Things I have tried that don't work:

```
String delimiters = " ,\\(\\)"; 

String delimiters = " ,[()]";

String[] s = in.readLine().split(Pattern.quote("() ,"));
```

I tried replacing the () using .replaceAll, didn't work

I tried this:

```
    input = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("("), " "); 
    input = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(")"), " ");
    input = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(","), " ");
    String[] s = input.split(" ");
```

but s[] ends up with blank slots that look like this -> "" no clue why its doing that

Comment: You need to use more... 1 to escape the first \, and 1 to escape what you are escaping, so that's 4 total.

Comment: isnt that what this `String delimiters = " ,\\(\\)"; ` does?

Comment: You need to use the pipe character as an `OR` clause `|` ... so something like `,|\\(|\\)` would be the general idea...

Comment: Wouldn't `String[] s = in.readLine().split(Pattern.quote("() ,"));` be `String[] s = in.readLine().split(Pattern.quote(" ,()"));`? That seems to be the pattern everywhere else? In any case I think Pattern.quote is the right direction.

Comment: There's many ways this can be done... I'm a bit unclear on what you're actually wanting to do.

Comment: @l'L'l I think you're right about the pipe, it kind of worked. Only problem left is I end up with blank slots in s[]. So for example s[0] = "". I am trying to fliter out everything here: " ,()". so thats a space, comma, and parens.

Comment: The character class method you tried should work also, but put the comma inside of it `[ ,()]` (and space too if you're using that also)...

Comment: why you are using " ,[()]", this will mean, that a "," followed by any of the bracket will be used as a delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Mine works, for

```
String delimiters = "[ \\(\\)]"
```

Edit:

You forgot Square brakcets which represents, "Any of the characters in the box will be used as delimiters", its a regex.

Edit:

To remove the empty elements: Idea is to replace any anagram of set of delimiters to just 1 delimiter

Like.

```
    // regex to match any anagram of a given set of delimiters in square brackets

    String r = "(?!.*(.).*\1)[ \\(\\)]";

    input = input.replaceAll(r, "(");

    // this will result in having double or more combinations of a single delimiter, so replace them with just one

    input = input.replaceAll("[(]+", "(");
```

Then you will have the input, with any single delimiter. Then use the split, it will not have any blank words.

Comment: Escaping `( )` inside a character class normally shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yea, right, good point. not necessary, but wont harm even if used. we can remove it safely.

Comment: this works but any idea why i might end up with "" in s[]?

Comment: but I am only input 1 line: (1,3), (6,5), (2,3), (9,1) and I need 13652391 so s[0] = 1, s[1]=3, ... but I get s[0] = "" s[1] = "" s[2] = 1, ...

Comment: yea, whenever  ",(" or ",)" are encountered, or delimiter is encountered togethor, it will produce an empty string.

Comment: If your line contains `), (`, and you're splitting on parentheses, commas and spaces, then you've got a number of splits in there. One between `)` and `,` (with the string between them being empty), another between `,` and the following space, etc. What you're trying to do isn't just split on a delimiter, it's more involved parsing.

Comment: There wont be an absolute way, as you have two split between these delimiters also. Just transform into some other array. or before processing it, put a check for empty.

Would be easy if it was java 8, could have used List<String> str = Stream.of(arr).filter(s -> !s.equals("")).Collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Yes: don't use regex, and instead writer a parser. Unfortunately, explaining how to do that is too broad for SO, and certainly for a comment. You could also try to find a parser for this syntax already; again, asking for one is off topic here (and I don't know of one offhand, anyway). If you have any control over the input syntax, I'd suggest using JSON, for which there are quite a few good parsers already out there.

Comment: Or, if all you need are the non-digits (and you don't care about the "structure" of the string other than that), then just use replaceAll with `"\\D"` as the input. The double-backslash in a String will turn into a single-backslash, so this will look like `\D` to Java; and that means "any non-digit." Replace that with an empty string, and there you go. `input.replaceAll("\\D", "")`.

Comment: looks like ill just be writing it myself, i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> but I am only input 1 line: (1,3), (6,5), (2,3), (9,1) and I need 13652391 so s[0] = 1, s[1]=3, ... but I get s[0] = "" s[1] = "" s[2] = 1

You get that because your delimiters are *either* " ", ",", "(" or ")" so it will split at every single delimiter, even if there is no other characters between them, in which case it will be split into an empty string.

There is an easy fix to this problem, just remove the empty elements!

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(
    "(1,3), (6,5), (2,3), (9,1)".split("[(), ]")).filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But then you get a `List` as the result instead of an array.

Another way to do this, is to replace "[(), ]" with "":

```
String result = "(1,3), (6,5), (2,3), (9,1)".replaceAll("[(), ]", "");
```

This will give you a string as a result. But from the comment I'm not sure whether you wanted a string or not. If you want an array, just call `.split("")` and it will be split into individual characters.